# How would I change an HTML theme to have a certain property when text is both bold AND italicized

Tags: html, theming, tumblr-themes

I'm not sure how to describe it, but if I had a code such as:

```
b, strong { font-weight: bold; font-size: 105%; }

i, em { font-style: italic; font-size: 105%; }
```

Those cause the theme to make it so that if the text is bold, then make it 105% bigger, and likewise for italicized, as I'm sure you know. How would I go about making it so that if the text is Bold AND Italicized, then it'll do something. For example, I want bolded and italicized text to be font-size: 115%, while keeping them individually at 105%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strong` and `em`, and save `b` and `i` for other things. Use this rule for things that are both bold and italicized:

```
strong em, 
em strong 
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the easiest approach would be to use classes for that, one for bold, the other for italic, and then just use:

```
.bold, .italic {font-size: 105%; }
.bold.italic {font-size: 115%;}
```

But maybe someone comes up with something that can work directly with tags.

---

See it here:

```css
.bold, .italic {font-size: 105%; }
.bold.italic {font-size: 115%;}
.bold {font-weight: bold}
.italic {font-style: italic}
```

```html
<span class="bold">I am BOLD</span><span class="italic">, I am ITALIC</span>, <span class="bold italic">and I am BOTH!</span>
```

Comment: Even though I posted my own answer, this is probably the way I would do it.

Comment: @ShaneLessard, yeah, I actually upvoted yours because it directly does what OP asked for (although it's not a good approach originally).